# Browser support Internet Explorer 10 - Compatibility Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, ie-compatibility-mode

I am developing an application using a proprietary front-end framework. The framework supported only Internet Explorer 7, 8 standards.

Now as a new requirement, we are testing our application in the Internet Explorer 10. I tried it in three personal computers having the same browser settings as described below.

**Internet Explorer Version:** 10.0.9200
**Browser Mode:** IE 10 compatibility View 
**Document Mode:** IE 7 standards

I tested the same UI in three systems and the page got rendered in two systems but I received a script error in one system and I am not able to find the reason for that error.

Error details in the below line at character 4: 

`Object doesn't support this action`

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

I am not able to find out the reason why the same application runs smooth in other browsers having the same settings.

Comment: Try using `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` instead, although according to MS, IE7 has support for native XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @Zaffy But the problem should occur in all the systems with the same browser settings. Why is that it renders properly in few but doesn't work in some?

Comment: Try using the F12 tools to verify that each machine is displaying the page in the same document mode.  I think you'll find that one isn't.  If they are consistent, then look into the add-ons used on each machine (and their versions) and the user's settings, including the compatibility view settings (available from the gear menu) and the security zone preferences/site lists.

Comment: @LanceLeonard They were in the same document modes. I guess it was due to some version problems in the updates. I disabled all add-ons and uninstalled the updates and tried installing again, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried running IEDigest (http://www.regente.de/IEDigest/) to compare the difficult machine with one that's working?

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that the IE settings (and version) is exactly identical across all 3 machines then a lot of factors can be considered with this issue and it can span from connectivity, specifications, etc. - anything that can differentiate one PC to another which will be difficult to identify.

For the benefit of the doubt, we can give a try on the following:

- Tweak your code to create the XMLHttpRequest object once the window
  loads

  window.onload = function() {
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

or

- Reset the IE settings of the machine where the app doesn't render
  properly

  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/reset-ie-settings#ie=ie-10

Comment: I am executing that code on load of the window already. I tried resetting them already. Didn't work. I guess this is a browser issue. When I upgrade to IE 10 from IE8, I am not able to access a lot of websites (tried them using different document modes too)

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Native XMLHTTP support" in IE browser under the tab Tools-> Advanced -> Security -> Enable Native XMLHTTP support .